# Performance of a bamboo (Phyllostachys) hedge in South-West UK

Tags: hedge, bamboo

I am considering a bamboo hedge. I want something with substantial culms, so *Phyllostachys sp.* and I would like them to stay green. I really like *P. glauca*. *P. bissettii* and *P. vivax* also look good.

I'm based on the southern edge of the Cotswolds, England, so it'll be exposed to mild, wet but blustery south-westerly weather. We get some frosts, but temps rarely drop below -5°C. Soil is free draining, over limestone. Beautiful texture, low in nutrients.

How would a bamboo hedge perform? What sorts of heights can I expect and what time for establishment? How would it look in winter? I am aware of the need for root barriers but depths, spacings and planting tips welcome.

Comment: I'm not far from you but with wetter, heavier soil, and a neighbour has a bamboo hedge that reaches 8ft+.  I don't know the species (or the neighbour, they're on another road but I walk past their house quite often).  It's not a massively exposed site but neither is it epsecially sheltered.  So I'm sure you can do it, it's just a matter of optimising.

Comment: I should probably add: soil is *exceptionally* free draining and can get quite dry in summer.

Comment: I have clumping bamboo in my back yard. They are about 25 feet or so, its genus is called bambusa. It stays pretty green.

Answer (score 4):

Fargesia Robusta,  one of the greatest bushing bamboo.

This bamboo is able to withstand harsh weather.  It will be safe between temperatures of 0 Degrees Fahrenheit - (17 degrees Celsius) and 90 degrees Fahrenheit - (32 degrees Celsius)

It can be used to create beautiful wall hedging around any area and it will stay quite green.  Bamboo usually is quite resistant, bugs do tend to get to it more then anything. That's with all bamboo.

Here is a site so you may read up on this specific bamboo and its ability to create a natural fence perimeter. This also applies to hedges using bamboo in general context to give you an idea for other types.

http://www.bamboogarden.com/Fargesia%20robusta.html

And here is a quote from [another site clarifying](http://www.greatplantpicks.org/plantlists/view/640) it will be perfect for you:

> **"Culture Notes"** 
>   This clumping bamboo grows best in rich moist to well-drained soils. It will tolerate sand or clay if drainage is adequate")

: Perfect for your area.

This Bamboo gets quite tall, many varietys tend to. You can expect heights for many bushing bamboo to reach about 20 feet or so.

Comment: Hi brandon. This is a very helpful answer. Would you mind posting a link to the second site, the one about "Culture Notes", so we can read the other information on the page? Thanks!

Comment: No problem, one second please

Comment: http://www.greatplantpicks.org/plantlists/view/640

Comment: That page indicates the bamboo I listed will reach up to 17 feet